# Understanding Emscripten/ASM.js and the browser sandbox

Tags: javascript, asm.js, transpiler

Sorry for the basic question here. I'm trying to wrap my head around Emscripten, ASM.js, and compiling lower level languages to javascript.

Here is what I don't understand. You can do things in a native C program that you can't (and shouldn't) do in browser based js. For example, in a native app you can access or the file system or shut the computer down.

Suppose I wrote a C program that reads /etc/passwd and then shuts the computer down. Then, I compiled that program to js and popped it in a `<script>` tag. What would happen when I visit the page with the `<script>` tag in it? Obviously, it's not going to shut the computer down, but would it even compile?

It just seems to me that javascript running in a browser is so limited compared to lower level languages that I can't see how any meaningful applications can be simply compiled to js without totally breaking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Emscripten docs](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html). For example, it says:

> Applications compiled with Emscripten usually expect synchronous I/O,
>   so Emscripten itself provides file systems with completely synchronous
>   interfaces.
>
> However, due to JavaScript’s event-driven nature, most persistent
>   storage options offer only asynchronous interfaces. Emscripten offers
>   multiple file systems that can be mounted with FS.mount() to help deal
>   with persistence depending on the execution context.

And if you scroll down there, you'll find this:

> ### MEMFS
>
> This is the default file system mounted at / when the runtime is
>   initialized. All files exist strictly in-memory, and any data written
>   to them is lost when the page is reloaded.

I believe that this should answer your question. At the end of the day, Emscripten/ASM will try to emulate low-level details with JavaScript-based polyfills.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did see that part of the docs actually, and it kind of makes sense. I guess I just see the things that can be done in the browser as such a small subset of the things a native app can do that I don't see how one can simply "compile" a native app to run in the browser. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DominicP Actually Emscripten is a transpiler from ASM to ASMJS, and Emscripten provides a set of JavaScript APIs to mimic native ones. That's all. How it does it? It translate native calls into JavaScript/ASMJS calls to their equivalents in Emscripten running either in the browser or Node.

Comment: yes, that much makes sense. But, what would be the JavaScript equivalent of the native call to shut down the computer, for example? Or, the native call to read data from a serial port? Or, the native call to read SMART data from a connected drive? Or... How could these kinds of things be mimiced in js?

Comment: @DominicP If something isn't supported, it won't be translated to JS at all. Obviously, Emscripten/ASMJS are limited to what JavaScript can do. I don't have a definitive answer to each case where JS has a limitation, but you can be sure that you can't use a serial port or shutdown a computer from a browser-based app. But Node can do it already so it will depend on the target enviroment.